# Adding photos to a venue using photos/add api and a simple form

Tags: foursquare

I am trying to implement a simple form that allows me to add photos to venues (there are 30+). I followed a guide [here](http://www.stephenkeable.co.uk/blog/development/create-a-foursquare-web-based-photo-uploader/) and changed a few things to match the current api. When I use the uploader, I get the JSON response below. Is everything in order? I am getting a 200 response, but I am not seeing the photos added to their respective venue. I have also included my html for the form I am using to upload, please take a look let me know if anything  is wrong. Thanks!

JSON Response:

```
{"meta":{"code":200},"notifications":[{"type":"notificationTray","item":{"unreadCount":0}}],"response":{"photo":{"id":"502ab14fe4b0ed9600d7722d","createdAt":1344975183,"prefix":"https:\/\/irs3.4sqi.net\/img\/general\/","suffix":"\/atVMrQ02CcgHIamCVmTugx4MCX4hIEVv1lLqbo24cnA.jpg","width":700,"height":525}}}
```

Form HTMl:

```
<form action="https://api.foursquare.com/v2/photos/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" v="20120809" >
<p>Venue ID: <input type="text" name="venueId"></p>
<p><input  type="file" name="photo"></p>
<input type="hidden" name="oauth_token" value="MY OAUTH TOKEN">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Are you uploading the same photo to multiple venues? The API will return a 200 on an upload, then suppress a photo if it detects the photo being a duplicate

Comment: Yes, for some of the venues we were trying to upload duplicate 'generic' images. I assume the server is comparing the actual data of the image and not just the filename on upload? is there a work around for this or should i just get unique images?

Comment: Only upload photos that were taken at the physical location (which, by definition, should be unique across venues)